# Sum of orders is zero, function field

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}(X)^\times$. Does it necessarily follow that$$\sum_{v \in \mathbb{CP}^1} \text{ord}_v(f) = 0?$$Here, $\text{ord}_v$ denotes the order of zero of $f$ at $v$.

**Update.** $C(X)^\times$ denotes the field of rational functions with complex coefficients.

Comment: What is $\mathbb{C} \mathbb P^1$?

Comment: @D_S We have $\mathbb{CP}^1 = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$.

Comment: @D_S : the [complex projective line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line#Complex_projective_line:_the_Riemann_sphere) I'd say, but what is $\mathbb{C}(X)^\times$ ? the multiplicative group of the field of meromorphic functions ? or something like that

Comment: for a meromorphic function $f$ :  $\int_{|z|=1} (\ln f(z))' dz$ computes the number of zeros minus the number of poles inside the unit disk. then, how do you  compute the number of zeros minus the number of poles OUTSIDE the unit disk ?

Comment: $f$ defines a morphism $\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$. For any point $Q\in\mathbb{P}^1$, the divisor $f^*(Q)=\sum \mathrm{ord}_P(f) P$ where $f(P)=Q$ and if $D$ is a divisor on $\mathbb{P}^1$, $\deg f^*(D)=\deg f\deg D$. In your case, you are taking $D=0-\infty$ and thus what you get is zero.

Comment: Is $X$ a variable or a curve or something else?

Comment: @Mohan $X$ is a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f$ as a fraction of two non-zero polynomials and so if we show this for a polynomial in $X$, we would be done, since $\mathrm{ord}_v(p/q)=\mathrm{ord}_v(p)-\mathrm{ord}_v(q)$. If $p(X)$ is a polynomial in $X$, $\sum\mathrm{ord}_v(p)=\deg p$, where $v$ runs through valuations from finite places. One easily checks that $\mathrm{ord}_{\infty} (p)=-\deg p$ and so you are done.